# C++ base and derived class method trouble

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have 1 base class named AddOns, this class has 9 derived classes. Also I have vector defined as shared_ptr

AddOnsContainer.h

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<AddOns>> container;
```

Now my problem is that I have defined a method in AddOns

AddOns.h

```
virtual void ChangeDefaultSearchProvider();
```

that I want to override in only one of the derived classes (SearchProviders). For every other derived class I want to use the code implemented in AddOns.h. The method is defined as virtual, which should have helped me, but my code still runs the base method for every one derived class even for the one that I have overrode.

Here is the definition from the method from the derived class that should do something different.

SearchProviders.h

```
virtual void ChangeDefaultSearchProvider() override final;
```

From here I call the method:

AddOnsContainer.cpp

```
void AddOnsContainer::ChangeDefaultSearchProvider(int pId)
{
    container[pId]->ChangeDefaultSearchProvider();
}
```

So could someone help me to understand how should I define the method in my base class, so that later on I can override it in only one of my derived classes.

Otherwise I should implement this method in each derived class, but as I know this is not the idea of OOP and inheritance.

Thank you all in advance!

Best Regards,
Mario P.

P.S.

This is the code where I add items(SearchProviders) to the vector:

```
SearchProvider searchProviders;

while (searchProviders.FindNext())
{
    add_item(searchProviders);
}
```

Comment: Looks correct, so the code where you create objects and add them to your vector would be relevant.

Comment: I recommend reducing your code to a mcve. If that doesn't help solving your problem, then post it here.

Comment: If I don't find any different solution to my problem, most probably I will try to reduce the code and post it here.

Comment: Slicing issue perhaps? Aside of this, do you have any proof that your derived objects in `container` are not all currently being treated as `AddOns`?

Comment: everything looks fine, there must be a problem somewhere else.
You can try it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6471P9)

Comment: you can put breakpoint at the call of ChangeDefaultSearchProvider and see what is the type of container[pId], maybe container[pId] is not the AddOn you think but something else

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with the code fragments or the vague description of the rest of the code. Most likely, the pointer doesn't point to what you think it does, but there's no way to guess why not without a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yet too less of code here to advise something specific. Also note that the prototypes of inherited functions must exactly match each other!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help!

I found the problem in my code during the process of creating minimal code.

The problem was in:
AddOnsContainer.cpp

```
void AddOnsContainer::ChangeDefaultSearchProvider(int pId)
{
    container[pId]->ChangeDefaultSearchProvider();
}
```

Because I pass `pId` directly, and I need to subtract 1, because currently I do not use the Graphic interface and I use only the console variant.

However, as it took me some time to create some minimal variation of my original code I decided to upload it to GitHub with link here in Stackoverflow.

The code can be access via:
https://github.com/mariopavlov/C/tree/master/InheritanceExample

Thank you again all!
Best,
Mario P.